# HTML dropdown only display label

Tags: html, angular, html-select, html-input

I want to create a Drop downlist with a search bar where you can type a string and choose a string but the value of the field is a number instead (not visibly).

However, everything i have tried lead to both the number and the string beeing displayed.
How can i fix this?
This is the HTML for the list.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>Owner:</label>
  </td>
  <td><input #owner type="text" name="owners" list="owners"></td>
  <datalist id="owners">
        <option *ngFor="let ownerElem in owners" value="{{ownerElem.id}}" label="{{ownerElem.name}}"/>
      </datalist>
</tr>
```

This is what it looks like

[image: This is what it looks like]

What do I have to change so the number is not displayed and also not filled in the text field when choosing a value?

Answer (score 0):

When using 'option', the 'value' is what's going to be displayed.

Try this approach.

```
<option *ngFor="let ownerElem in owners" (change)="selectOwnerElem(ownerElem)">{{ownerElem.name}}</option>
```

You should create a function 'selectOwnerElem' that's going to do the logic when an option is selected.

Comment: Thanks. It looks the same though. 
I tried this: 
<option *ngFor="let ownerElem in owners" (change)="selectOwnerElem(ownerElem)" value="{{ownerElem.name}}"></option>

and this 
<option *ngFor="let ownerElem in owners" (change)="selectOwnerElem(ownerElem)" >Test</option>

It all looks the same

Comment: With the code I wrote, you shouldn't be getting the value in the HTML. Whats the problem?

Comment: I have no idea can i be because i am using chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<option 
*ngFor="let ownerElem in owners" 
(change)="selectedOwnre($event)"
[value]=ownerElem.id >
{{ ownerElem.name }}
</option>
```

ts file

```
selectedOwnre(event){
 console.log(event)
}
```

Comment: Using this approach you can display the Name as option and while selecting the name you can get the id of corresponding option.

Comment: Thanks. It still looks the same somehow it always displays both. Can it be because i am using chrome?

Comment: I think no issues with using chrome, It should work, Please try simply copy pasting my code.

Comment: I copy pasted it. It did not print anything when choosing. 
Then I added "console.log('event')"  that wasnt printed as well.

Comment: Please check this example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghepmo